# Azure Functions Script Compilation Failed

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to create an Azure Function with Docker. When I create a Function with `func new`, it works fine and when I go to http://localhost:8182/api/HttpTriggerCSharp?name=John I get the message

> Hello, John

Now I'm trying to run the same project but I changed the code. The previous code was this:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string name = req.Query["name"];

string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
name = name ?? data?.name;

return name != null
    ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
    : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Now this is my new code:

```css
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
 log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

 // Parsing query parameters
 string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
 .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
 .Value;
 log.Info("name = " + name);

 string numberOfTerms = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
 .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "numberOfTerms", true) == 0)
 .Value;
 log.Info("name = " + numberOfTerms);

 // Validating the parameters received
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberOfTerms))
 {
  var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                                       "Please pass a name and the number of digits on the query string."); 
  return errorResponse;
 }

 int termsToShow;
 try
 {
   termsToShow = Int32.Parse(numberOfTerms);
 }
  catch (FormatException e)
 {
  var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                                       "The numberOfTerms parameter must be an integer!"); 
  return errorResponse;
 }

 if (termsToShow < 0 || termsToShow > 100) {
   var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                                       "Please pass a numberOfTerms parameter between 0 and 100."); 
  return errorResponse;
 }

 // Building the response
 string incompleteResponse = "Hello, " + name + ", you requested the first " + numberOfTerms + " terms of the Fibonacci series. Here they are: ";
 string completeResponse = GenerateFibonacciTerms(incompleteResponse, termsToShow);
 var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, completeResponse); 

 // Returning the HTTP response with the string we created
 log.Info("response = " + response);
 return response;
}

public static string GenerateFibonacciTerms(string incompleteResponse, int termsToShow)
{    
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    string temporalString = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < termsToShow; i++)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp + b;
        temporalString = temporalString + temp.ToString() + " ";
    }

 string result = incompleteResponse + temporalString + "- That's it, have an awesome day!";
 return result;    
}
```

I build the container then I run it and I get this message:
[image]

I've already checked my code with VS Code (I did it in Sublime Text so I didn't have code checking) and all the problems it finds are the same error:
[image]

And my code has "errors" everywhere:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are all the required packages included?

Comment: How can I tell if I have included all the packages? VS Code says that some assembly references are missing but I see no missing "usings"

Comment: Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio. However, it worked following the instructions that Jerry gave me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using v2 function core tools(based on .net core), while the code you changed is targeted at v1(.net framework).

So you have two choices:

1. Uninstall v2 and use function core tool v1.
2. Modify your code to make it work in v2 runtime.

Here the code for you to refer. `GenerateFibonacciTerms` method needs no change.

```
log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

// Parsing query parameters
string name = req.Query["name"];
log.Info("name = " + name);

string numberOfTerms = req.Query["numberOfTerms"];
log.Info("numberOfTerms = " + numberOfTerms);

// Validating the parameters received
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberOfTerms))
{
    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name and the number of digits on the query string."); 
}

int termsToShow;
try
{
     termsToShow = Int32.Parse(numberOfTerms);
}
 catch (FormatException e)
{
    return new BadRequestObjectResult("The numberOfTerms parameter must be an integer!"); 
}

if (termsToShow < 0 || termsToShow > 100) {
     return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a numberOfTerms parameter between 0 and 100."); 
}

// Building the response
string incompleteResponse = "Hello, " + name + ", you requested the first " + numberOfTerms + " terms of the Fibonacci series. Here they are: ";
string completeResponse = GenerateFibonacciTerms(incompleteResponse, termsToShow);
var response = new OkObjectResult(completeResponse); 

// Returning the HTTP response with the string we created
log.Info("response = " + response);
return response;
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks for answering again! I'll try this when I get home and I'll tell you.

Comment: I made the modifications to my code and it worked, thank you so much!!